# Which process does the $PATH environment variable belong to?

Tags: environment-variables

Environment variables must belong to a process, right? It seems that there are de facto "global" environment variables like $PATH and $HOME. Which process do they belong to?

Answer (score 3):

There is not a single PATH variable, and it doesn't belong to a single process.

Each process has an **environment**, which consists of a list of key-value pairs. The keys are usually named "variables". The `export` command lists that environment. Processes inherit their environments from their parents (and in UNIX, you inherit even before your parent dies. Isn't that nice?).

You can put any variables into the environment, for example `export birthday="Jan 23"`, but some variables have a special meaning for the shell, such as HOME or PATH. Other variables have a special meaning for certain programs; for example, see the [ENVIRONMENT section](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html#ENVIRONMENT) in the manual page for the `man` command.

In summary, each process has PATH and HOME.

Answer (score 0):

Environment is typically passed to a new process by [execve](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) using a pointer to a memory area holding an array `envp`.

```
   int execve(const char *pathname, char *const argv[],
              char *const envp[]);
```

The environment is often iherited, but also basically built from for example reading `/etc/environment` (core $PATH). Bourne shell reads `/etc/profile` in addition to local profile files etc.

In addition to the above, [POSIX exec*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) could be of use to read.